# How many hours have I spent in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Is there a way to see how many real world hours I spent in the game? I see people saying "I played for 50 hours" "I played for 200 hours", Is there a way to find that our or is that just an estimate?

Comment: I have to say, I would never want to know how much time I've spent on Skyrim.  It would just make me feel bad.

Comment: Oh man, I love the word "shovelware".  I've got to start using that!

Comment: As of today.....too many?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since all copies of Skyrim uses steamworks, Steam will keep track of how many hours you've spent in the game, assuming you have been online while playing.

If you go to your profile, you'll see your playing time to the right of your profile.

If you have been offline most of the time, then there is another way to very roughly estimate your playing time:

When you are loading your character, there is a series of numbers beneath the name that looks like this:

> 031.57.15

The first 3 digits represents the number of hours, the middle 2 the minutes, and last 2 the seconds.  That is how 'old' your character is.  This doesn't keep track of reloads, however.

If you add all these values up across all your characters, you can estimate your playing time.

Comment: Hmm, been offline for a big part of it. No way to see it in the save files or something?

Comment: If you are playing on a console, then checking the save games is the main way of getting the amount of time spent.

Comment: Only PC versions of Skyrim use Steam

Answer (score 5):

For console gamers, the amount of hours played shows up under the information about your save file on the load/save files screens.

Answer (score 1):

Highlighting a game from your Steam library will shown the number of hours played (not counting time in offline mode) next to the Play button.